# Can I sync up multiple image onload calls?

Tags: javascript, image, function, onload

I want a function to run when specific images are loaded, but I don't know how to wait for both to load before running. I only know how to chain them, like below:

```
Image1 = new Image();
Image1.src = 'image1-link.jpg';

Image2 = new Image();
Image2.src = 'image2-link.jpg';

Image1.onload = function() {
    Image2.onload = function() { ... }
}
```

The downside to this is it has to wait till Image1 completely loads before getting the second. I want to try something like this:

```
Image1 = new Image();
Image1.src = 'image1-link.jpg';

Image2 = new Image();
Image2.src = 'image2-link.jpg';

(Image1 && Image2).onload = function() { ... }
```

EDIT: Thank you both for the help Paul Grime and ziesemer. Both your answers are very good. I think I have to give the best answer to Paul Grime, although his uses more code, I only need to know the src of the images and the onload function is built in while in ziesemer's answer I need to know both the src, the count of the images, and have to write multiple onload lines.

Depending on the situation, both have their purpose. Thank you both for the help.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is available

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This fiddle might help. It's a simple generic 'loader'.

http://jsfiddle.net/8baGb/1/

And the code:

```
// loader will 'load' items by calling thingToDo for each item,
// before calling allDone when all the things to do have been done.
function loader(items, thingToDo, allDone) {
    if (!items) {
        // nothing to do.
        return;
    }

    if ("undefined" === items.length) {
        // convert single item to array.
        items = [items];
    }

    var count = items.length;

    // this callback counts down the things to do.
    var thingToDoCompleted = function (items, i) {
        count--;
        if (0 == count) {
            allDone(items);
        }
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        // 'do' each thing, and await callback.
        thingToDo(items, i, thingToDoCompleted);
    }
}

function loadImage(items, i, onComplete) {
    var onLoad = function (e) {
        e.target.removeEventListener("load", onLoad);

        // this next line can be removed.
        // only here to prove the image was loaded.
        document.body.appendChild(e.target);

        // notify that we're done.
        onComplete(items, i);
    }
    var img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", onLoad, false);
    img.src = items[i];
}

var items = ['http://bits.wikimedia.org/images/wikimedia-button.png',
             'http://bits.wikimedia.org/skins-1.18/common/images/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png',
             'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4a/Commons-logo.svg/30px-Commons-logo.svg.png',
             'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Icons_example.png'];

loader(items, loadImage, function () {
    alert("done");
});
```

Answer (score 11):

If you can't use something like jQuery, create a helper function that you can pass to the `onload` of all your images you are interested in.  Each time it is called, increment a counter, or add the `src` name to a set.  Once the counter or your set reaches the size of all of the images that you are expecting, then you can fire off whatever work you really wanted to do.

Something like:

```
var imageCollector = function(expectedCount, completeFn){
  var receivedCount;
  return function(){
    if(++receivedCount == expectedCount){
      completeFn();
    }
  };
}();

var ic = imageCollector(2, function(){alert("Done!");});
Image1.onload = ic;
Image2.onload = ic;
```

Answer (score 1):

I took Paul Grime's example above and modified it to be more understandable while still accomplishing the OP need. I felt the other answers here were either to complicated or not enough. Hopefully this code is a little easier to pick up and put in. I used underscore for the each loop, but this is easy to change.

Also, I improved the solution now to have a callback for on img error. If the image is loaded, it is added to the array, if it fails it is not. I also changed it to utilize jquery.

```
var loadedImages = [],
    imagePaths = [{"src": "myimg.png"}, {"src": "myotherimg.png"}];

loadImages(imagePaths, loadedImages, function(loadedImages) {
    console.log(loadedImages)
});

function loadImages(imagePaths, loadedImages, callback) {
    if (!imagePaths) { return; }

    var count = imagePaths.length;

    _.each(imagePaths, function(data, key, list) {
        var onLoad = function (e) {
            count--;
            if (0 == count) {
                callback(loadedImages);
            }
        }

        $(document.createElement("img"))
            .on('load', function() {  
                loadedImages.push(data);
                onLoad();
            })
            .on('error', function() {  onLoad(); })
            .attr("src", data["src"]);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsing existing answers I was surprised that no one has implemented a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) based solution which in my opinion is the most elegant and suitable for such a problem, so here is one:

```js
// Example array of images
const imageUrls = [
  "https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki.png",
  "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4a/Commons-logo.svg/30px-Commons-logo.svg.png",
];

// imageUrls.map returns Promise array (because callback function is async), 
// which is immediately passed to Promise.all which accumulates them into one
// promise which will be resolved when all its elements will finish.
Promise.all(
  imageUrls.map(async (imageUrls, i) => {
    const tmpImage = new Image();
    
    // Create synchronization promise
    const syncPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    
      tmpImage.onload = (e) => {
        // Handle loaded image
        console.log("Finished loading image: ", i);
        
        // Don't forget to resolve syncPromise
        resolve(); 
      };
      
      tmpImage.src = imageUrls;
    });
    
    // Wait for syncPromise (image loaded)
    await syncPromise;
  })
).then(() => {
  console.log("Finished loading all images");
});
```