# tick method in javascript for canvas

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a tick method for this code.

When I try to put a while loop or time interval it just goes blank.

I want the tick method to call this function without the canvas going blank.
How would i make that tick method

```html
function setup(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 600;
 var gun = new Image();
 var badguy = new Image();
    var wall1 = 200;
    var ground = new Image();
    var back = new Image();
 var back2 = new Image();
 var back3 = new Image();
    var wall = new Image();
    var wall2 = new Image();
back.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(back, 0, 0, 800, 300);
};
back2.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(back2, mountainplace, 0, mtnsize1, 300);
};
back3.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(back3, mountainplace2, 0, mtnsize2, 300);
};
ground.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(ground, groundplace, 300, 1980, 200);
};
wall.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(wall, place2, 250, size2, 100);
};
wall2.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(wall2, place, 250, size, 100);
};
 badguy.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(badguy, badguyplace, 250, 100, 100);
};
gun.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(gun, 0, 100, 400, 400);
};
back2.src = "moutain1.png";
back3.src = "moutain2.png";
back.src = "backing.png";
ground.src = "ground1.jpg";
wall.src = "wall.png";
wall2.src = "wall2.png";
badguy.src = "santa2.png";
gun.src = "gun1.png";
};
```

Comment: Where is your tick function? What do expect it to do exactly? Please provide a complete example. *"Im having to put more words in because it says its mostly code and it."* Providing a better explanation would solve that as well.

Comment: i want it to call this without the canvas going blank

Comment: As I said, please provide a **complete** example that reproduces the issue. You are talking about a `while` loop and interval, but I don't see any in your example. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clarify the question because I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve.

I **assume** you put some code at the end of your setup() function that performs some operations on the images. But before you can do it you need to wait for the images to load.

BTW: another problem with your code is that the images will be drawn on the canvas in the order in which they load, which may be unpredictable. You probably want to avoid this too.

A solution to your problem (or at least to what *I* think your problem is) is to first start loading the images and then only perform further operations after they have **all** been loaded.

You can use the following code to do this:

```
function makeAllLoadedHandler(image_files_count, on_all_loaded) {
  return function() {
    --image_files_count;
    if (image_files_count == 0) {
      // All images loaded, call the function.
      on_all_loaded();
    }
  }
}

function loadAllImages(image_files, on_all_loaded) {
  var images = {};
  var callback = makeAllLoadedHandler(image_files.length, function() { on_all_loaded(images); } );
  for (var i = 0; i < image_files.length; ++i) {
    var image = new Image;
    image.src = image_files[i];
    image.onload = callback;
    images[image_files[i]] = image;
  }
}
```

The `loadAllImages()` function takes an array of image file names and a function to call when all the images have been loaded.

You can use it like this in your code:

```
function setup() {
  var image_files = [
    "mountain1.png",
    "mountain2.png",
    "backing.png",
    "ground1.jpg",
    "wall.png",
    "wall2.png",
    "santa2.png",
    "gun1.png" ];

  loadAllImages(image_files, onAllImagesLoaded);
}

function onAllImagesLoaded(images) {
  // Draw your images and perform all the other tasks on them.
  // The 'images' object stores each of the Image object under a key that is
  // its file name.
  ctx.drawImage(images['backing.png'], 0, 0, 800, 300);

  // ...
  // Do other stuff with the images.
}
```

You just call the `setup()` function like you used to and then the `onAllImagesLoaded` function will be called some time later when all the images are available. You continue your processing in there.

I hope this helps. Although it's possible that your problem is completely different ;)

Comment: Actually there's cleaner code to achieve the same thing in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682085/can-i-sync-up-multiple-image-onload-calls/8682318#8682318