# How to wait until onload event completes its work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm developing a printing tool using HTML5 canvas. As a test, I've tried to draw an image and a rectangle on the canvas, and then copy it to a new window for printing, using the code below, but all I'm getting in the new window is a blank page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
   <canvas id="pageCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("pageCanvas");
    canvas.height="700";
    canvas.width="1000";
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageData="data:image/png;base64,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";
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = imageData;
    imageObj.addEventListener("load", function() {
            ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 50, 100,1000,600);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(100, 101, 200, 100);
            ctx.lineWidth = 7;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.stroke();
    }, false);
    var printWindow = window.open('');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><BODY>');
    printWindow.document.write('<center>');
    printWindow.document.write('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL()+'"/>');
    printWindow.document.write('</center></body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.print();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can you please guide me to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You're opening the new window and trying to copy the content of the canvas onto it immediately after *attaching* the `load` event handler to the image, before the handler has actually had a chance to execute.

Just move all the JS code starting with the `var printWindow = window.open('');` line *inside* the event handler, and it should work.

Oh, and please indent your code, especially if you expect anyone else to read it.

---

Addendum: If you want to wait until multiple images have loaded, the simplest way is to count the load events and call a function when all of them have fired, like this:

```
var imageURLs = [ ... image URLs here ... ];
var imageObjs = [];
var imagesLoaded = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener( "load", function() {
        imagesLoaded++;
        if (imagesLoaded == imageURLs.length) allImagesLoaded();
    } );
    image.src = imageURLs[i];
    imageObjs.push(image);
}
function allImagesLoaded() {
    // now do something with imageObjs
};
```

You could also get fancy and play with things like ES6 [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but ultimately, the end result is the same.

See also:

- [Can I sync up multiple image onload calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682085/can-i-sync-up-multiple-image-onload-calls)
- [Javascript - wait images to be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104346/javascript-wait-images-to-be-loaded)

Comment: Thanks @IImari, yes it working. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No, not really. Any code you want to execute after the image has loaded has to be in the `load` event handler, or called from it. That's how asynchronous execution works in JavaScript.

Comment: @llmari : any idea if i have multiple images in my html5 canvas?

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj: You can increment a counter in the `load` event handler, and call a function when the counter reaches a certain value; see edit above.