# JS Image not showing up on canvas

Tags: javascript, drawimage

I have a bird={} object where I define a draw function, however the image does not appear when called in the render function. Could anyone point me to what Im doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have noticed the reason it does not always show up is because there are other sprites on the screen, and when I turn them off the bird always show up. Is there anything that can fix this?

```js
bird = {
    draw:function() {
        var birdimg = new Image();
        birdimg.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(birdimg, -20, height - 200);
        }
        birdimg.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/nsZLM.png"; //"assets/bird.png";
    }
};

function main() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    //Set the width and height to the sizes of the browser
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;

    //Frames the game if the width is larger than 500
    if(width >=500){
        width = 320;
        height = 480;
        canvas.style.border = "1px solid #000";
        evt = "mousedown";
    }

    //Sets the canvas sizes to the width and height variables
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //Set the default state
    currentstate = states.Splash;

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    render();
}

function render(){
    //Adding bird
        bird.draw();


        //Loads sky.png
        bgimg = new Image();
        bgimg.onload = function() {

            ctx.drawImage(bgimg,-20,height-200);
            ctx.drawImage(bgimg,256,height-200);

        }

        bgimg.src = "assets/sky.png";

        //Loads land img
        landimg = new Image();
        landimg.onload = function() {

            ctx.drawImage(landimg,0,height-100);



        }

        landimg.src = "assets/land.png";

        //Creates rectangle that colors background. THIS IS THE BOTTOM LAYER. WRITE CODE ABOVE

        ctx.fillStyle="#4ec0ca";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        ctx.stroke();

}
```

Comment: main() is never called? `states` doesn't exist, and the asset is only existing on your local computer (you need to upload it). Also consider using variables to store values.

Comment: I didnt write it on here, but it is on the original code. About the original question, would you have anything to kindly suggest?

Comment: You could upload the bird image (use the image upload button in the editor) and link your img src to that instead, so we can check if the bird is drawn outside the canvas area or not. Also shave down the example included in the question so it's runable (without using `states`, or at least with states defined, calling main() etc.).

Comment: Also check the console (F12) for any error messages when you run the code locally

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsZLM.png This is what the image looks like. I cannot upload it into the main comment as it gives me an error.

Comment: Updated the post with the new image link. It seem to work when main() is called and `states` are commented out, as per Nicholas' answer?

Comment: I found what's wrong. Since I have more sprites added to the game, it seems somehow it goes under the other sprites. What can cause this? (Updated main code).

Comment: asynchronous loading is the cause. The better approach IMO is to preload all assets, then reference them when in use. You need to use the load event with a handler to know when an asset is loaded. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33916649/how-to-wait-until-onload-event-completes-its-work-in-javascript/33916794#33916794 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33916649/how-to-wait-until-onload-event-completes-its-work-in-javascript/33916794#33916794 (there are a ton more similar answers).

Answer (score 1):

Following @K3N's suggestions here is a working example. Thanks @K3N for the guidance.

With these changes your code would look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    // declare vars so they are available outside of main()
    var canvas,
        ctx,
        width,
        height;

    var bird = {
        draw: function() {
            var birdimg = new Image();
            birdimg.src ="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg";

            birdimg.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(birdimg, -20, height - 200);
            };
        }
    };

     function main(){
       canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

       //Set the width and height to the sizes of the browser
       width = window.innerWidth;
       height = window.innerHeight;

       //Frames the game if the width is larger than 500
       if(width >=500){
         width = 320;
         height = 480;
         canvas.style.border = "1px solid #000";

         var evt = "mousedown";
       }



       //Sets the canvas sizes to the width and height variables
       canvas.width = width;
       canvas.height = height;
       ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

       //Set the default state
       // "states" is not defined so I'm commenting this out
       // var currentstate = states.Splash;

       document.body.appendChild(canvas);

       render();
    }

    main();

    function render(){
      //Adding bird
      bird.draw();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/luheni/4/edit?html,console,output)

Hope this helps,
Nick Leoutsakos

Comment: "Hint: values must be positive and should only include numeric values". There is no problem drawing an image using negative values (ie. transforms; canvas will clip regardless). You can try inserting negative values in the linked jsbin you made and you'll see there are no problems.

Comment: Thanks @K3N. You're definitely right about that. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: Unfortunately still not entirely correct since you are allowed to evaluate an expression as argument, ie. height - 200 is evaluated to a number since height is set already. There are many issues in OPs code but the call to drawImage() is not one of them (unless the calculation is such that the bird is drawn outside the visible canvas - he's not showing us so we won't know what assets/bird.png looks like).

Comment: Thanks again @K3N. Totally correct. Edited to reflect.